# many threads with same progressbar

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

i have the following scenario algorithm
which copy specific file to all drives  in a disk

```
Copyfile()
{
   for(int i=0;i<drivesnumber;i++)
       {
          t = new Thread(() => MoveProgressBarwhilecopying()
          t.joint()
       }

}
MoveProgressBarwhilecopying()
{
   DoCopy
   if(progressbar1.InvokeRequired)
     CopyingprogressBar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { CopyingprogressBar.Increment(1); }))

}
```

my problem is that iam copying a file across all disk and i want a one and only one progressbar to handle this operation

and becuase of joint operation which is necessary  for all threads which are run in the loop to not overlap

i wasn't able to invoke progress bar 
,any suggetions please to run multiple threads with same progress bar and with joint operation

Comment: The "question" is unclear. In any case, I suspecta "problem" is not deriving the percentage from num_processed / total (incrementing to 100 by 1 is only valid if there *are* 100 steps). Also, calling Thread.Join before the *other* threads are created blocks creation of subsequent threads: if the threads should not run in parallel, create only one thread. For WinForms, use a BackgroundWorker unless there is need for manual Threads. It also helps to post code that will actually compile (`joint` is an unresolved identifier and there are missing parenthesis, etc)..

Answer (score 0):

You progressbar is probably running in one thread (UI thread) and next to that you have the other threads do the work they have to do (worker threads).

If so, you have to be aware that the threads doing the work might finish at nearly the same time, e.g. 1ms apart, and ask the progress bar to increase by 1. What could happen is that the progress bar is still in the process of increasing while you ask it to increase again from another thread. The variable that holds the count might not have been updated yet. This causes all sorts of unwanted behavior, concurrency problems. That ranges from display problems to crashes and deadlocks. It could also be that your worker threads are taking so much cpu time that the UI thread doesn't get enough cpu time to be able to refresh the progress bar in time.

So the solution to your problem is probably that you have to protect your progress bar from being accessed concurrently. And you can do so by using a monitor, mutex, semaphore or even sockets. Depending on your particular goal, some might be better suited than others.
The other part is making sure that the UI thread gets enough time to refresh the progress bar while other threads are claiming cpu time to do their work.

Comment: i want to mention that the purpose of using thread was because without

Comment: i want to mention that the purpose of using thread was because without thread i wasn't able to use progress bar because the form will not respond after some time ,i don't have to use threads in parallel but i want to call the method MoveProgressBarwhilecopying to fill progressbar from 1 to 100 then i want the progress bar to go to minimum value a gain and increment another time to 100 in the second call of MoveProgressBarwhilecopying thats why i had to use joint but how can i access a progressbar now because without using joint i was able to ,is that impossible in my algorithm